# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\sideProjects\loginTut\db.php on line 20

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi i have checked other responses to this problem but for some reason i can't solve the problem.This is a login system i am trying to create but i keep getting the  Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in...According to the error the problem is in the db.php file.Here it is..

```
<?php
require "config.php";


function DBconnect($config) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $config['database'],
                        $config['username'],
                        $config['password']);

        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $conn;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getmessage();
    }
}

function query($query, $bindings, $conn) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);

    return $stmt;
}
```

And here is my index.php file which for creating the login page.

```
<?php

// include the necessary files
require "db.php";
require "functions.php";
include "index.view.php";

// Allow sessions to be passed so we can see if the user is logged in
session_start();

//conect to the database so we can check, edit or ,data to our users table
DBconnect($config);

// if the user has submitted the form
if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    global $conn;
    //protect the posted value then store them to variables
    $username = protect($_POST["username"]);
    $password = protect($_POST["password"]);

    //Check if the username or password boxes were not filled in
    if ( !$username || !$password ){
        // if not display an error message.
        echo "You need to fill in a username and password!";
    }else
        // if correct continue cheking

        //select all the rows where the username and password match

        query(  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
            array("username" => $username),
            $conn);
        $num = ( $stmt->rowcount() ); 


        //check if there was not a match
        if( $num == 0) {
            //if not display an error message
            echo "The username you entered does not exist!";
        }else{
            //if there was a mactch continue chekcing

            //select all rows where the username and password match the ones submitted by the user
            query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =:username && password = :pasword",
                    array("username" => $username, "password" => $password ),
                    $conn);
            $num = ( $stmt->rowcount() );   

            //check if there was not a match
            if( $num == 0) {
                //if not display error message
                echo "Username and password do not mactch";
            }else {
                //if there was continue checking

                //split all the fields from the correct row into an associative array
                $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                //check to see if the user has not activated their account
                if($row["active"] != 1) {
                    //if not display an error message
                    echo "You hav not yet activated your account!";
                }else {
                    //if so then log them in

                    // set the login session storing their id. We use this to
                    // see if they are logged in or not.
                    $_SESSION["uid"] = $row["id"];
                    //show message confirming that they are loggd in
                    echo "You have succesfully logged in!";
                    //update the online field to 50 seconds in the future
                    $time = date("u")+50;
                    query( "UPDATE users SET online = :time WHERE id = :id",
                            array("time" => $time, "id" => $_SESSION["uid"]),  
                            $conn);
                    //redirect them to the usersonline page
                    header("Location: usersOnline.php");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You are not assigning `$conn` anywhere. The `return` in the function alone will not magically make it appear outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign a value to `$conn` from the return value of `DBConnect()`, eg

this

```
DBconnect($config);
```

should be

```
$conn = DBConnect($config);
```

You also don't need to use `global $conn` in your script as it will be in scope.

I'd also recommend not catching the exception from the `PDO` constructor. How else will you know something went wrong? `echo`-ing the exception message does not deal with the error.

And yet one more thing, put `session_start()` at the top of your script or at least above the `include` statements. If any of them output data to the browser, you'll get the old *"headers already sent"* error.

#### Update

Now that I've looked a little closer at your question, why are you wrapping the `PDO` methods in user functions like `query()`? You aren't adding anything here so why not just use the `PDO` object directly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put global $conn inside the DBConnect function

```
function DBconnect($config) {
    global $conn;
    //...
}
```

or assign the return value of DBConnect to `$conn`

Comment: OK, why the -1?? It just works, wheather other solutions could be cleaner..